# Fill space below plot in 3d projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to fill the area underneath a curve in a 3D plot. In 2d plots I've already used fill_between for something similar. Is there an easy equivalent to that in 3d environment? The curve is in the y-z plane.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))



x=[-1,0,1,2,3,4]
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
sigma=0.4
m=1
b=1

Blankz=np.empty([0])
Blanky=np.empty([0])
Blankx=np.empty([0])
j=0
for i in np.arange(-0.5,2.5,0.01):
    Blankz=np.insert(Blankz,j,gaussian(i,1,sigma))
    Blanky=np.insert(Blanky,j,i)
    Blankx=np.insert(Blankx,j,0)
    j=j+1


fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-1,5)
ax.set_ylim(-1,6)
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
plt.plot(x,y,0, color="blue",linestyle="dashed")

plt.plot(Blankx,Blanky,Blankz, color="red")
ax.view_init(60,320)
```

[image]
Basically I want a fill_between function that fills the area in the range of  y=-0.5,2.5 from z=Blankz[i] to z=0. I want the area of the gaussian distribution to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/collections_api.html) and [`add_collection3d`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.add_collection3d):

```
verts = [list(zip(Blanky, Blankz))]
poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[mcolors.to_rgba('y', alpha=0.6)])
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=[Blankx[0]], zdir='x')
```

**Full code**:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors


def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

x=[-1,0,1,2,3,4]
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
sigma=0.4
m=1
b=1

Blankz = np.empty([0])
Blanky = np.empty([0])
Blankx = np.empty([0])

for j, i in enumerate(np.arange(-0.5, 2.5, 0.01)):
    Blankz = np.insert(Blankz, j, gaussian(i,1,sigma))
    Blanky = np.insert(Blanky, j, i)
    Blankx = np.insert(Blankx, j, 0)



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-1,5)
ax.set_ylim(-1,6)
ax.set_zlim(0,2)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")

# create vertice and add it
verts = [list(zip(Blanky, Blankz))]
poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[mcolors.to_rgba('y', alpha=0.6)])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=[Blankx[0]], zdir='x')

plt.plot(x,y,0, color="blue",linestyle="dashed")
plt.plot(Blankx,  Blanky, Blankz, color="red")
ax.view_init(60,320)
plt.show()
```

*output*:
[image]